# need help converting string to unicode and then add values

Tags: python

I need help converting this code to lower cases, then substring to remove spaces then find the ASCII values then add them up to get a sum, this is what I wrote:

```
def main ():
    # Handshake
    print("This program computes a total value for a user's full name")

    # Prompt and read input
    fullname = input("Please enter your full name: ")

    # Convert user's full name to all lower case letters
    fullname = fullname.lower()

    # Split user's full name into substrings
    fullname = fullname.split()

    # Loop through each substring and compute
    # total ASCII value of user's name
    totalvalue = 0
    for character in fullname:
        fullname = ord(character) + totalvalue

    #Display outputs
    print("\nYour name is: ", fullname)
    print("\nThe value of your name is: ", totalvalue)

main()
```

Comment: no question mark found!

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:  (1) After splitting, fullname is now a list of names, so you need a second loop to iterate over the characters, and (2) you typed `fullname` instead of `totalvalue` when summing in the loop.  Try replacing the loop with:

```
totalvalue = 0
for name in fullname:
    for character in name:
        totalvalue += ord(character)
```

Comment: so write a second loop for the characters after splitting them?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this where you use a list comprehension:

```
import sys

def main ():
    # Prompt and read input
    text= raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
    values = [ord(c) for c in text]
    print(values)
main()
```

where values is a list of the ascii values for the string, you can prob do the rest from there